# I can't get my PHP "else" conditional block to work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, if-statement

I have a function to get a tire size from the database and display it. The else, which should function when the size isn't in the database, isn't working.

Here is my code for the function:

```
 function tiresize() {
    global $db;

    if (isset($_POST['size'])) {
        $_SESSION['size'] = $_POST['size'];
        $size = $_SESSION['size'];
        // $size=mysql_real_escape_string($size);
        // trim($size);
    }


    if (isset($size)) {
        $query = $db->prepare("SELECT size FROM tires WHERE size = '$size'");
        $query->execute();

     $tires = $query->fetchAll();
        if (isset($tires)) {
            echo "<ul>";
            foreach ($tires as $name) {
                echo "<li id='tiresearch'>";
                echo "Tire Size is Available: " . $name['size'];
                echo "</li>";
            }
     } else {
            echo "Tire size was not found";
         echo "</ul>";
        }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are validating if `$tires` is set (and not to `null`), while you should check if you've fetched anything but an empty array(*in other words, if there are records in the database*), you can use `!empty($tires)`, *for example*.

Answer (score 0):

When u check `isset($tires)`, the program essentially checks if the variable is not null. That means there could be an empty array, so it is best to check something like   `if ($tires != array()) {` (line 12)